# Minishift does not start after after installation

Tags: docker, minishift

I'm trying to run open shift locally on my machine, so I downloaded Oracle Virtual box VirtualBox-5.2.20 to run the mini shift virtual machine. The problem is when I want to start mini-shift using the mini shift start it does not start.

I get the following :

```
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Using proxy for the setup
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.10.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.10.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'virtualbox' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if VirtualBox is installed ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor ...
-- Starting Minishift VM ........................-- Setting proxy information ... .OK
..... OK
-- Checking for IP address ... OK

-- Checking for nameservers ... OK
-- Checking if external host is reachable from the Minishift VM ...
   Pinging 8.8.8.8 ... FAIL
   VM is unable to ping external host
-- Checking HTTP connectivity from the VM ...
   Retrieving http://minishift.io/index.html ... OK
-- Checking if persistent storage volume is mounted ... OK
-- Checking available disk space ... 1% used OK
-- OpenShift cluster will be configured with ...
   Version: v3.10.0
-- Pulling the Openshift Container Image .....................................................................................................................................................................Error pulling the openshift container image: ssh command error:
command : docker pull openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.10.0
err     : exit status 1
output  : Trying to pull repository docker.io/openshift/origin-control-plane ...
v3.10.0: Pulling from docker.io/openshift/origin-control-plane
aeb7866da422: Pulling fs layer
8bd69565c444: Pulling fs layer
37c5cca65a4a: Pulling fs layer
250356f18bea: Retrying in 3 seconds
250356f18bea: Retrying in 2 seconds
250356f18bea: Retrying in 1 second
250356f18bea: Verifying Checksum
250356f18bea: Download complete
unexpected EOF
```

Comment: Hello! Which minishift version are you currently running? Also: is this your first try on getting minishift started, or was it already working for you?

Comment: minishift-1.23.0-windows-amd64

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a problem pulling the OpenShift container images from Docker Hub. Is this issue reproducible?

I recommend you try:

```
$ minishift delete --clear-cache
$ minishift start --vm-driver virtualbox
```

If that fails repeatedly, you can see whether some extra logging can shed some light on this:

```
$ minishift --v 5 start --vm-driver virtualbox
```